# How do I convert MP4 video file to M4V using FFMPEG?

Tags: video, encoding, ffmpeg

I have tried to convert video file as:
**ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -an -ar 44100 -b 300k -s 320*240 -vcodec mpeg4 output.m4v**

Comment: What's wrong with the result of the above file?

Answer (score 1):

```
$ ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vcodec copy -acodec copy out.m4v
```

Comment: This is wrong. M4Vs are raw streams of exactly one MPEG-4 Part-2 video stream. Since OP has a MP4, it will have, likely, a H264 stream (+ audio)

Comment: Shouldn't `ffmpeg` warn/complain about it then? Here's my output - https://gist.github.com/snobu/be4f349938ce00a517634300a39c9590

Comment: Unfortunately, Apple has co-opted `.m4v` for their ipod files - notice `Output #0, ipod, to 'out.m4v':` in your log. You have to add `-f m4v` for the raw bitstream. Maybe we should force it the other way around.

Comment: So, can you guys let me know what is the exact solution for this?

Comment: Which format do you need - how are you going to use the result?

Comment: @Gyan, _Maybe we should force it the other way around._ -- That would be a breaking change frowned upon by many. May i suggest printing a warning instead - `results may not be what you expect, be aware of -f, <link to something more verbose>.`

Comment: I need to convert mp4 to m4v using FFMPEG. I have written command as **Heading of the question I've asked so, please check**

Comment: This guy is hopeless.

Comment: Please be gentle here @evilSnobu. I'm not using any bad comments outta here so, please

Comment: You're right, i apologize. However, you should really describe what you're trying to achieve since there are 2 other people now investing their time trying to figure that out and it's not ok.

Comment: @Bhaumik, there are two formats with extension `m4v` - which one do you want?

Comment: It's okay @evilSnobu. I just started this Yesterday so, m new in this so, little confused but as I have written MP4 to M4V so, any format will work I guess.

Comment: @gyan  not mentioned which format I have to used so, any format will work

Answer (score 0):

I was under the impression that .m4v was video with no audio and .m4a was like aac audio with no video. If you join them together you get an .mp4 file, or so it seems. $ ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -an out.m4v